# Overriding Implicit Rules in Makefiles

Tags: linux, makefile

My Makefile contains an implicit rule override in the form of an explicit rule definition. However, make still invokes the default implicit rule.

This is on RHEL 6.3, GNU Make Version 3.81.

```
CPPFLAGS = -Wall -O2

DEPDIR = .d
DEPFLAGS = -MT "$@ $(DEPDIR)/$*.d" -MMD -MP -MF $(DEPDIR)/$*.d

SRCS = $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

%.o: %.cpp $(DEPDIR)/%.d
        g++ -c $< $(CPPFLAGS) $(DEPFLAGS) -o $@

$(DEPDIR)/%.d: $(DEPDIR) ;

$(DEPDIR):
        mkdir -p $@

include $(wildcard $(DEPDIR)/*.d)

.PHONY: clean clobber
clean:
        rm -f *.o
        rm -rf $(DEPDIR)
```

Invocation of 'make' outputs this:

```
[tlytle@tlytle-dev]$ make
g++  -Wall -O2  -c -o my_source.o my_source.cpp
```

Why is make invoking the default implicit rule for %.o files and not my explicit rule for %.o files defined in my Makefile?

Comment: I don't see any explicit rule, and it's not possible for there to be an explicit rule for a pattern (by definition).  Maybe you are misusing the terms "implicit" and "explicit" as they apply to make?  But without understanding what you mean there's no way we can understand your question.

Comment: Oh, maybe you mean _default_ rules where you are using implicit rules?  That seems likely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not *overriding* the default rule for building .o files from .cpp files.  In order to override it you'd need to define a new rule with identical target *and* prerequisites; your implicit rule has extra prerequisites, so you're just *adding* a new implicit rule that could build a .o file.

The rules for choosing implicit rules when multiple ones may match can be confusing.

The simplest thing to do is [delete the builtin rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html) so that it's not available to be considered.  You can do this by defining an implicit rule with the same target and prerequisites as the builtin rule, but no recipe:

```
%.o : %.cpp
```

Now make will have no choice but to use your implicit rule.

Note that GNU make 3.81 is really old.  In newer versions of GNU make you can delete all the builtin rules to start by adding this to your makefile:

```
MAKEFLAGS += -r
```

Comment: *"Note that GNU make 3.81 is really old..."* - Red Hat (and CentOS) supply antique software out of the box. It is one of the reasons I despise working on the platforms.

Comment: `The rules for choosing implicit rules when multiple ones may match can be confusing.` I used to think that it's "one with all prerequisites existing (no chain); or the first match otherwise" (I assume that all stems are of equal length). Is it really more complex?

Comment: That is not quite the right rule; in any event it doesn't cover various special cases.  The full algorithm is here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rule-Search.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd start from trying to run it with `--no-builtin-rules` to prove/disprove the theory about implicit/default (both are legit terms) rules being involved.

The [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html#Canceling-Rules) says, that for an override to work both the target and prerequisites must match, and in your case it's not. Could be that.